# Navigation from one webview to another

Tags: android, webview

I have created a webview in which if an external link is clicked it goes to another webview with the loaded external link. I wanted it in such a way that it goes back to the page it is navigated from if my back button is clicked. For example If I navigate from 4th page of main webview to some external link webview and If I click back it should go back to the 4th page and not 1st page. This is my XML page for reference.

```
 <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/external_webview">
</WebView>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ext_link"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backtonews"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/refresh"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:singleLine="false">
        </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the last page you were at in 1st web view before you go to 2nd one then listen to back key and then pop the 1st web view up with saved address

Let me know if you wanted more detail.

Comment: I couldn't write the back functionality for it. Can you share me details on how to do it.

Comment: You always can do manual action when back key pressed by overriding the onBackPressed method:
   `@Override`
`public void onBackPressed() {`
`super.onBackPressed();`
`// do your work here`
`}`

Comment: I can write normal back functionality but I want to know how to store the last page we were at in 1st web view  in code

Comment: It's quiet simple:
`String webUrl = webView.getUrl();`
store it as anyway you like.
static variable, database, file, preferences, ....

Comment: For all the pages they have the same URL, so If it from 1st page or from 4th page they still have the same URL. Is there any way I can deal with this ?

Comment: oh, their method is POST?

Comment: the webview contains horizontal scrolling. In that webview each thumbnail of that page is displayed as each page in android and there is no way of calling them separately. So if i go back it comes from the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110140/discussion-between-reaching-out-and-mohammad-z).